# On conflict do nothing with a custom constraint

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to do the following:

```
insert into table_a (primarykey_field, other_field)
select primarykey_field, other_field from table_b b
on conflict (primarykey_field) where primarykey_field >>= b.primarykey_field do nothing;
```

Nevermind the operation of my where condition it could be anything except a simple equal. in mycase I'm using a custom ip range field soI I want to check that one ip address is not in the range of the other ip adderss when I'm inserting a new row.

Is there a way I can do this with `on conflict` or with another query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter out all rows which have a `pkey_ip_range` that's already contained by an existing `pkey_ip_range`:

```sql
insert into table_a as a (
    pkey_ip_range, 
    other_field)
select  pkey_ip_range, 
        other_field 
from table_b b
where not exists (
    select 1 
    from table_a 
    where b.pkey_ip_range >>= table_a.pkey_ip_range);
```

If you wanted to check if the incoming ip range either contains or is contained by the existing ip range ([`&&` rather than `>>=`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/functions-net.html)), you can use an [exclusion](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/sql-createtable.html#SQL-CREATETABLE-EXCLUDE) constraint:

```sql
drop table if exists table_a;
create table table_a (
    pkey_ip_range inet primary key, 
    other_column text);
alter table table_a
add constraint table_a_no_contained_ip_ranges
exclude using gist (pkey_ip_range inet_ops WITH &&);

insert into table_a 
(pkey_ip_range,other_column) 
values ('192.168.0.0/31','abc');

insert into table_a 
(pkey_ip_range,other_column) 
values ('192.168.0.0/30','def');
```

> ```
> ERROR:  conflicting key value violates exclusion constraint "table_a_no_contained_ip_ranges"
> DETAIL:  Key (pkey_ip_range)=(192.168.0.0/30) conflicts with existing key (pkey_ip_range)=(192.168.0.0/31).
> ```

```sql
insert into table_a 
(pkey_ip_range,other_column) 
values ('192.168.0.0/32','ghi') 
on conflict do nothing;
table table_a;
```

| pkey_ip_range | other_column |
| --- | --- |
| 192.168.0.0/31 | abc |

Comment: The primary key field is the ip range and if the ip range of the new insert already exists it shouldn't insert. In other word the conflict is on the primary key which is the iprange and I need a custom constraint like contains rather than equals.

Comment: In that case you can simply filter out the rows where your ip_range is contained by one of the ip ranges in your primary key column, with a simple `where not exists`. I've updated my answer.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid `not exists` because it is more costly than `on conflict` because these are rather large tables I am dealing with. Do you know how to achieve this logic with a `custom trigger`?

Comment: On second thought, it can be achieved through the `on conflict` clause after all, as long as you can actually force this situation to be a conflict by constraining the column using an [exclusion](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/sql-createtable.html#SQL-CREATETABLE-EXCLUDE). While `unique` does a plain equality check, `exclude` can use a custom comparison, like `>>=` you're after.

Comment: Late edit: the operation in `exclude` must be commutative, and `>>=` isn't. If you were checking the incoming ip ranges both ways, `existing_ip_range>>=incoming_ip_range or existing_ip_range<<=incoming_ip_range` which ends up being `existing_ip_range&&incoming_ip_range`, then this could work with `&&` in the exclusion constraint.

Comment: @docHoliday I've updated my answer to include a demonstration of the exclusion constraint approach.